# Altering jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using the [vegas slider](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) as a background image for a site I am building. I have it working and configured to my liking, however my end goal is to be able have a random image load every page load.

I have seen methods on how to do that separately but I am not quite sure how I would alter/add on to this existing js to implement that.

Any helpful links or tutorials or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
( function( $ ){
    var $background = $( '<img />' ).addClass( 'vegas-background' ),
        $overlay    = $( '<div />' ).addClass( 'vegas-overlay' ),
        $loading    = $( '<div />' ).addClass( 'vegas-loading' ),
        $current    = $(),
        paused = null,
        backgrounds = [],
        step = 0,
        delay = 5000,
        walk = function() {},
        timer,
        methods = {

        // Init plugin
        init : function( settings ) {
            var options = {
                src: getBackground(),
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'center',
                fade: 0,
                loading: true,
                load: function() {},
                complete: function() {}
            }
            $.extend( options, $.vegas.defaults.background, settings );

            if ( options.loading ) {
                loading();
            }

            var $new = $background.clone();
            $new.css( {
                'position': 'fixed',
                'left': '0px',
                'top': '0px'
            })
            .imagesLoadedForVegas( function() {
                if ( $new == $current ) {
                    return;
                }

                $( window ).bind( 'load resize.vegas', function( e ) {
                    resize( $new, options );
                });

                if ( $current.is( 'img' ) ) {

                    $current.stop();

                    $new.hide()
                        .insertAfter( $current )
                        .fadeIn( options.fade, function() {
                            $('.vegas-background')
                                .not(this)
                                    .remove();
                            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegascomplete', [ this, step - 1 ] );
                            options.complete.apply( $new, [ step - 1 ] );
                        });
                } else {
                    $new.hide()
                        .prependTo( 'body' )
                        .fadeIn( options.fade, function() {
                            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegascomplete', [ this, step - 1 ] );
                            options.complete.apply( this, [ step - 1 ] );    
                        });
                }

                $current = $new;

                resize( $current, options );

                if ( options.loading ) {
                    loaded();
                }

                $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasload', [ $current.get(0), step - 1 ] );
                options.load.apply( $current.get(0), [ step - 1 ] );

                if ( step ) {
                    $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegaswalk', [ $current.get(0), step - 1 ] );
                    options.walk.apply( $current.get(0), [ step - 1 ] );
                }
            })
            .attr( 'src', options.src );

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Destroy background and/or overlay
        destroy: function( what ) {
            if ( !what || what == 'background') {
                $( '.vegas-background, .vegas-loading' ).remove();
                $( window ).unbind( 'resize.vegas' );
                $current = $();
            }

            if ( what == 'overlay') {
                $( '.vegas-overlay' ).remove();
            }

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Display the pattern overlay
        overlay: function( settings ) {
            var options = {
                src: null,
                opacity: null
            };
            $.extend( options, $.vegas.defaults.overlay, settings );

            $overlay.remove();

            $overlay
                .css( {
                    'margin': '0',
                    'padding': '0',
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'left': '0px',
                    'top': '0px',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'height': '100%'
            });

            if ( options.src ) {
                $overlay.css( 'backgroundImage', 'url(' + options.src + ')' );
            }

            if ( options.opacity ) {
                $overlay.css( 'opacity', options.opacity );
            }

            $overlay.prependTo( 'body' );

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Start/restart slideshow
        slideshow: function( settings, keepPause ) {
            var options = {
                step: step,
                delay: delay,
                preload: false,
                backgrounds: backgrounds,
                walk: walk
            };

            $.extend( options, $.vegas.defaults.slideshow, settings );

            if ( options.backgrounds != backgrounds ) {
                if ( !settings.step ) {
                    options.step = 0;
                }

                if ( !settings.walk ) {
                    options.walk = function() {};
                }

                if ( options.preload ) {
                    $.vegas( 'preload', options.backgrounds );
                }
            }

            backgrounds = options.backgrounds;
            delay = options.delay;
            step = options.step;
            walk = options.walk;

            clearInterval( timer );

            if ( !backgrounds.length ) {
                return $.vegas;
            }

            var doSlideshow = function() {
                if ( step < 0 ) {
                    step = backgrounds.length - 1;
                }

                if ( step >= backgrounds.length || !backgrounds[ step - 1 ] ) {
                    step = 0;
                }

                var settings = backgrounds[ step++ ];
                settings.walk = options.walk;

                if ( typeof( settings.fade ) == 'undefined' ) {
                    settings.fade = options.fade;
                }

                if ( settings.fade > options.delay ) {
                    settings.fade = options.delay;
                }

                $.vegas( settings );
            }
            doSlideshow();

            if ( !keepPause ) {
                paused = false;

                $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasstart', [ $current.get(0), step - 1 ] );
            }

            if ( !paused ) {
                timer = setInterval( doSlideshow, options.delay );
            }

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Jump to the next background in the current slideshow
        next: function() {
            var from = step;

            if ( step ) {
                $.vegas( 'slideshow', { step: step }, true );

                $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasnext', [ $current.get(0), step - 1, from - 1 ] );
            }

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Jump to the previous background in the current slideshow
        previous: function() {
            var from = step;

            if ( step ) {
                $.vegas( 'slideshow', { step: step - 2 }, true );

                $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasprevious', [ $current.get(0), step - 1, from - 1 ] );
            }

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Jump to a specific background in the current slideshow
        jump: function( s ) {
            var from = step;

            if ( step ) {
                $.vegas( 'slideshow', { step: s }, true );

                $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasjump', [ $current.get(0), step - 1, from - 1 ] );
            }

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Stop slideshow
        stop: function() {
            var from = step;
            step = 0;
            paused = null;
            clearInterval( timer );

            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasstop', [ $current.get(0), from - 1 ] );

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Pause slideShow
        pause: function() {
            paused = true;
            clearInterval( timer );

            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegaspause', [ $current.get(0), step - 1 ] );

            return $.vegas;
        },

        // Get some useful values or objects
        get: function( what ) {
            if ( what == null || what == 'background' ) {
                return $current.get(0);
            }

            if ( what == 'overlay' ) {
                return $overlay.get(0);
            }

            if ( what == 'step' ) {
                return step - 1;
            }

            if ( what == 'paused' ) {
                return paused;
            }
        },

        // Preload an array of backgrounds
        preload: function( backgrounds ) {
            var cache = [];
            for( var i in backgrounds ) {
                if ( backgrounds[ i ].src ) {
                    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
                    cacheImage.src = backgrounds[ i ].src;
                    cache.push(cacheImage);
                }
            }

            return $.vegas;
        }
    }

    // Resize the background
    function resize( $img, settings ) {
        var options =  {
            align: 'center',
            valign: 'center'
        }
        $.extend( options, settings );

        var ww = $( window ).width(),
            wh = $( window ).height(),
            iw = $img.width(),
            ih = $img.height(),
            rw = wh / ww,
            ri = ih / iw,
            newWidth, newHeight,
            newLeft, newTop,
            properties;

        if ( rw > ri ) {
            newWidth = wh / ri;
            newHeight = wh;
        } else {
            newWidth = ww;
            newHeight = ww * ri;
        }

        properties = {
            'width': newWidth + 'px',
            'height': newHeight + 'px',
            'top': 'auto',
            'bottom': 'auto',
            'left': 'auto',
            'right': 'auto'
        }

        if ( !isNaN( parseInt( options.valign ) ) ) {
            properties[ 'top' ] = ( 0 - ( newHeight - wh ) / 100 * parseInt( options.valign ) ) + 'px';
        } else if ( options.valign == 'top' ) {
            properties[ 'top' ] = 0;
        } else if ( options.valign == 'bottom' ) {
            properties[ 'bottom' ] = 0;
        } else {
            properties[ 'top' ] = ( wh - newHeight ) / 2;
        } 

        if ( !isNaN( parseInt( options.align ) ) ) {
            properties[ 'left' ] = ( 0 - ( newWidth - ww ) / 100 * parseInt( options.align ) ) + 'px';
        } else if ( options.align == 'left' ) {
            properties[ 'left' ] = 0;
        } else if ( options.align == 'right' ) {
            properties[ 'right' ] = 0;
        } else {
            properties[ 'left' ] = ( ww - newWidth ) / 2 ;
        }

        $img.css( properties );
    }

    // Display the loading indicator
    function loading() {
        $loading.prependTo( 'body' ).fadeIn();
    }

    // Hide the loading indicator
    function loaded() {
        $loading.fadeOut( 'fast', function() {
            $( this ).remove();
        });
    }

    // Get the background image from the body
    function getBackground() {
        if ( $( 'body' ).css( 'backgroundImage' ) ) {
            return $( 'body' ).css( 'backgroundImage' ).replace( /url\("?(.*?)"?\)/i, '$1' );
        }
    }

    // The plugin
    $.vegas = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[ method ] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist' );
        }
    };

    // Global parameters
    $.vegas.defaults = {
        background: {
            // src:         string
            // align:       string/int
            // valign:      string/int
            // fade:        int
            // loading      bool
            // load:        function
            // complete:    function
        },
        slideshow: {
            // fade:        null
            // step:        int
            // delay:       int
            // backgrounds: array
            // preload:     bool
            // walk:        function
        },
        overlay: {
            // src:         string
            // opacity:     float
        }
    }

    /*!
     * jQuery imagesLoaded plugin v1.0.3
     * http://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded
     *
     * MIT License. by Paul Irish et al.
     */
    $.fn.imagesLoadedForVegas = function( callback ) {
        var $this = this,
            $images = $this.find('img').add( $this.filter('img') ),
            len = $images.length,
            blank = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

        function triggerCallback() {
            callback.call( $this, $images );
        }

        function imgLoaded() {
            if ( --len <= 0 && this.src !== blank ){
                setTimeout( triggerCallback );
                $images.unbind( 'load error', imgLoaded );
            }
        }

        if ( !len ) {
            setTimeout( triggerCallback, 200 );
            // triggerCallback();
        }

        $images.bind( 'load error',  imgLoaded ).each( function() {
            // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
            if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){
                var src = this.src;
                // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
                // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
                this.src = blank;
                this.src = src;
            }
        });

        return $this;
      };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a jquery functon which ramdomize the array of images and return, then assigned the returned array

```
        { src: 'images/background4.jpg', fade: 4000 },
        { src: 'images/background3.jpg', fade: 4000 },
        { src: 'images/background2.jpg', fade: 4000 },
        { src: 'images/background1.jpg', fade: 4000 }
```

to the background option of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can call the plugin with any img src parameter like that:

```
$( function() {
  $.vegas({
    src:'/images/background.jpg'
  });
});
```

Just get the random filename from PHP/Ruby/Python or whatever your backend is. Or you can create a JavaScript array and select a random item from it.

Comment: I have called the function that way. Like I said, I'm able to get a single image just find. Just want to put a bunch of images in a folder and have a random image display PER page load

Comment: And the answer says: "Put a bunch of images in a folder and write the paths in a JS array. After that select a random one from this array"

Answer (score 0):

Just went a super easy route and used `<?php echo rand(1,7); ?>.jpg'` in the src:

Comment: IMO this is essentially what @cnkt said (and similar to the other)--I'd consider accepting that answer and perhaps commenting or editing the answer to include the PHP-specific solution.

Comment: Instead of using the rand() function (Which is going to give you duplicated paths, I would put them in an array and use array_shuffle instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if it's too late but i found a solution to this problem.

**First step create a function for shuffle an array :**

```
function shuffle(o) {
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
```

**Second step create an array with your pics sources and params, then use the shuffle function :**

```
var vegasArray = [
    { src: "/pic1.jpg", fade: 1000},
    { src: "/pic2.jpg", fade: 1000},
    { src: "/pic3.jpg", fade: 1000},
    ...
];
shuffle(vegasArray);
```

**Last Step add your array into vegas slider params :**

```
$.vegas(
    'slideshow', {
        delay: 13000,
        backgrounds: vegasArray
    })(
    'overlay', {
        src: 'img/overlay.png',
        opacity: 0.9
    });
```

It's normally done! Hope that helped! :)